# How can i pass value to component dynamicly

Tags: json, reactjs

So i have few arrays. 1st is a file array and 2nd is choice array.
Choice array example {name:sks,src:skd}, ...etc
Image array look like that:
'sks':skdka

So name and src will change and that depends from out choice...

So i need to pass choice.name as a selector to 1st array
so i cant do it like that:

> images.choice.name becouse !== images.sks

so inside component i call function image, like that:

```
src={this.image(choice.name)}
```

that solution dont work

```
image(pos){
 return images.pos;
}
//pos === string and expected value sks
```

that solution work as expected but it is not dynamic...

```
image(pos){
 return images.sks;
}
```

any idea?

Comment: Your post is unclear and unreadalbe, If you want help, rewrite it.

Comment: ye you are right. I hope now it will be clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I get your post right. You have an json object for choosing the element in shape:

```js
choices = [
  {
    name:sks,
    src:skd
  },
...
]
```

and you have image object in shape of:

```js
const images = {
   "skd" : sdfsd,
   "asdasf": adadada
}
```

If my assumptions are correct then you should do it simply like:

```
const getImage = (choice) => images[choices.src]
```

Comment: Dzięki. jestem już zbyt zmęczony... miałem to ale images.[choices.src] i był błąd node modules i nie wgłębiałem się w to ale leciałem dalej xD fakt działa ;p dzieki